# Yum is not pulling latest FreeIPA (4.8.7) for CentOS 7.7

Tags: centos, ldap, redhat, ipa, freeipa

The latest freeIPA version is 4.8.7 as per the https://www.freeipa.org/page/Downloads, but when tried getting it on a fresh vanilla CentOS 7.7 box, yum is unable to fetch the 4.8.7 version, but instead it shows only 4.6.6.

Is there an additional step/repo required for this?

```
[root@ipaserver ~]# cat /etc/redhat-release
CentOS Linux release 7.7.1908 (Core)

[root@ipaserver ~]# yum info ipa-server | grep Version
Version     : 4.6.6
```

Answer (score 1):

RHEL 7 / CentOS 7 is only providing FreeIPA 4.6. This is the last version with Python 2. If you need FreeIPA 4.8, you should be looking at RHEL 8 / CentOS 8.